# Ruby on Rails display activeRecord contents on HTML page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am a ruby on rails beginner and am having some trouble displaying the contents of a database query on my html page.  I have a list of compounds that I would like to print to the webpage.
In my controller I have the code:

```
@info = Info.where.not(compoundName: 'Empty').pluck(:compoundName)
```

And in my views page I have the code:`

```
<td><%= @info %></td>
```

which prints out the contents in the form: ["compound1","compound2",...].  Instead I would like to iterate over this and print each one on its own separate line.  I have tried the code:

```
<% @info.each do |c| %>
            <li><%= c %></li>
<%end %>
```

but this returns an invalid byte sequence error.
I then tried:

```
<% @info.each do |c| %>
            <%= puts c %>
<%end %>
```

but that just prints to my terminal instead of the webpage.  Can someone explain how to print out the contents of my query to an HTML page?
Thanks!

Comment: Your view is an html.erb file correct?

Comment: Yes, it is called search.html.erb

Comment: Your first style should work. You could always try to interpolate your variable: `#{"c"}`

Comment: Do you mean trying: <%@info.each do |c| %> <%= #{"c"} %>  ?  Using that gave me a bunch of other errors...

Comment: `but this returns an invalid byte sequence error` could you please post the whole error message, together with backtrace? This is a completely correct approach.

Comment: The error is: "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"

Comment: @adub - which line is this code being thrown exactly? It seems you have some corrupted/non utf-8 data in your database. limiting results to find out which record is causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your `@info` results are valid, this query works just fine:

```
<% @info.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c %></li>
<% end %>
```